# Facebook has unpublished all my pages with no reason whatsoever

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, account-management

Facebook one day logged me out of my Android Phone app and browser on laptop and on top of that unpublished all of my pages. I had not post anything in any of those pages in the recent times. I never spammed nor shared links that could violate their policy. I am not able to contact Facebook or seek support from an individual. This is really upsetting and is hurting my business a lot. I have run out of money and new clients are telling me that I do not have a Facebook page, which I do, and they are turning back, which made me wonder how many of the clients avoided the call or email only.

I noticed a lot of people facing this issue in Support but Facebook does not reply well. How do I solve this?

Comment: "with no reason whatsoever" is probably less than accurate.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not visit your pages and make updates periodically, and there is little or no activity, Facebook will sometimes disable the pages because they are assuming that if you don't update them, then they aren't active anymore.

If this is what happened, then all you have to do is update the page and republish it, and then update it periodically.

If it is disabled for another reason, there should be a message from Facebook telling you why they disabled it, and then take appropriate action as outlined in their message.

But if the only thing about the page was that it wasn't updated in awhile and they disabled it, then all you have to do is republish it and make some updates to go live again.